# React native: how to show 12.3432523523% as 12.34%?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a value after calculating and got a fraction with too much numbers after digit.
I want to draw max 2 numbers after '.'

any solution?

i tried .toFixed(2) but didnt work.

edit:

```
let percent = (querySnapshot.size * 100) / this.state.numOfReg;
                                percent.toFixed(2)
                                rowData.push(percent + '%');
```

Comment: with C I'd do %2d in here not working and i dont want to set the maxLength of the text field

Comment: Can you add the evaluation being performed?

Comment: can you add the exact thing you're doing?

Comment: `12.3432523523.toFixed(2)` works

Comment: edited the post, since I calculate the number its not updating the toFixed, I must set a state for that local calculating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Number` object to access the [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function.

> **Return value:** A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.

```
let percent = (querySnapshot.size * 100) / this.state.numOfReg;
percent = Number(percent).toFixed(2); // <-- convert and save result
rowData.push(percent + '%');
```

```js
console.log(Number(12.3432523523).toFixed(2) + '%');
```

Comment: tnx for the answer,
but on my console log: 36.36363636363637
why it does that to me :(

Comment: @Try2prog `toFixed` doesn't mutate number object, it returns a formatted string. You'll either want to save the formatted string, or more likely you'll want to store the actual number value and save the formatting for when you render the data into your table row.

Comment: yes now i see the results is working. but the render on the screen making me the problem. I calculate lot of queries and draw it on table. now in console log it shows me well but on the emulator not updated

Comment: percent = Number(percent).toFixed(2) fixed it. 
thank you for the answer, I appreciate that